# Android Memory Analysis

Tags: android

I have to search for memory leaks in an Application at the moment and have a workflow problem. This ( http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html ) blog post states:

> If you're running ADT (which includes a plug-in version of DDMS) and
>   have MAT installed in Eclipse as well, clicking the “dump HPROF”
>   button will automatically do the conversion (using hprof-conv) and
>   open the converted hprof file into Eclipse (which will be opened by
>   MAT).

But wen I press the button within eclipse and try to open the hprof file I get this error - so I still have to do the conversion:

> Error opening heap dump 'com.baseapp.foo.hprof'. Check the error log
>   for further details. Error opening heap dump
>   'com.baseapp.foo.hprof'. Check the error log for further details.
>   Unknown HPROF Version (JAVA PROFILE 1.0.3) (java.io.IOException)
>   Unknown HPROF Version (JAVA PROFILE 1.0.3)

anyone knows what I am doing wrong here? I am using ADT 16

Comment: yea, but the answer from smith324 was way more helpful - so he got the bounty

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had this issue on my setup also, it seems there is a certain series of steps that cause eclipse to default to saving to a file (instead of doing the conversion and opening it).

Anyway to fix it:

Preferences (The global Eclipse ones) -> Android -> DDMS -> HPROF Action -> set to "Open in Eclipse" (Mine was previously on "Save to Disk")

Comment: thanks a lot - that was the hint i needed! enjoy your bounty!!

Answer (score 9):

Convert hprof file take from Android OS into standard hprof format. For this you can use hprof-conv tool that is located at AndrodiSDK/tools/hprof-conv.

Like this

```
hprof-conv android.hprof mat.hpof
```

And then open mat.hprof in Memory Analyzer.

Comment: yea I am doing this at the moment, but that is a bad workflow and the blog states " .. will automatically do the conversion .. " - hence this question

Comment: I am not facing the issue.I also have ADT 16.

Comment: so you do not have to do "hprof-conv android.hprof mat.hpof" ?

Comment: yes... I had this issue earlier and used to resolve this by the dirty way which i mentioned.Then one day i updated everything and it started working.... Try to do the same :P

Comment: Hmm Very Strange.What OS you are using?

Comment: I am using ubuntu linux with eclipse 3.7.0 / Memory Analyzer 1.1.1.201108240735 and ADT 16

Comment: Need to do the manual step on OS X as well. In 2014. All tools up to date.

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that there are additional details in the error log (Window > Show View > Error Log). Can you clear the log, then reproduce the problem, then see what if anything appears in the error log to help pinpoint the problem?

Comment: there is only one error showing up in this error log and there seems to be no connection to MAT/DDMS: "Invalid preference page path: XML Syntax" without real details 

eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.6.0_23
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64