# Is it possible to trigger an Android heap dump from the command line?

Tags: android, heap-dump

I would like to be able to trigger an Android heap dump from the command line. Is there a command for that?

**Specifically, from the command line, not via Montior or DDMS GUIs**

Maybe something like using ddms or adb, e.g. `ddms -head-dump` or `adb shell heapdump`? AFAICT monitor and ddms always start in GUI mode, and adb doesn't have a heap dump command.

Update: I tried this, it looked promising, but it doesn't work:

1. `adb jdwp`
2. `adb forward tcp:8000 jdwp:1234` (substitute output of 1 for 1234)
3. `jmap -dump:format=b,file=heapdump.hprof localhost:8000`

But even the heap summary fails:

```
jmap -heap localhost:8000
Attaching to remote server localhost:8000, please wait...
Error attaching to remote server: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
        java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

Comment: FWIW I was able to connect to the forwarded JDWP port via `jdb -attach localhost:8000`

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Live" memory analysis tool for Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483714/live-memory-analysis-tool-for-android)

Comment: Nah, that guy is explicitly looking for something that **is not** a heap dump, I am looking a heap dump via command line.

Comment: The answer under that question uses adb to get the heap dump via kill -11 <pid> that triger a full  gc and dump of heap in hprof. So what do you mean be heap dump ?

Comment: Interesting, unfortunately it looks like as of this commit (https://github.com/android/platform_dalvik/commit/c9dcf262db56d831eb45bb44978a6261e16a2d78?diff=unified) in 2010 (!) SIGUSR1 no longer heap dumps

Comment: Nope. THe file is missing description i notcied. I linked the proper file in answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Android pre 3.0 you can use so called

`kill -10 <pid>` ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6483906/390695))

In Android 3.0 a new command-line tool has been added:

`adb shell am dumpheap <pid> <output-file-name>;` ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954420/how-to-automate-the-ddms-snapshot-mechanism))

[Detailed description](https://github.com/android/platform_dalvik/blob/d09fa663f37fd26b4aea4e243b71660b9feacf37/docs/heap-profiling.html)

To get HPROF you need also change the format of it using [hprof-conv](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hprof-conv.html)

Comment: Wow, awesome, this was really hard to find, thanks. Should be `adb shell am dumpheap <pid> <output-file-name>` ("shell" was missing) Worth noting that the out file name has to be user writable, so e.g. write to /sdcard/heapdump.hprof

Comment: debug is also required

Comment: And output-file-name is optional. The default is `/data/local/tmp/heapdump-<date>-<time>.prof`

Comment: pid can also be replaced with package name.

Answer (score 8):

The easy way:

```
adb shell am dumpheap your.package.name /sdcard/dumpheap.hprof
```

The hard way (don't remember why I've added it originally):

```
adb shell am dumpheap $(ps | grep your.package.name | awk '{print $2}') /sdcard/dumpheap.hprof
```

If your device doesn't have `awk` try to use `busybox awk`.

After that pull the created file, convert it with [hprof-conv](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/investigate-ram.html#hdanalyze) and open it in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

**For those who do not want each time look for correct PID and just wanna use one-line command**

Add this this to your .zshrc or .bashrc:

```bash
heap_dump() {
    PACKAGE=$1
    HPROF=/data/local/tmp/$PACKAGE.hprof
    PID=$(adb shell ps | grep $PACKAGE$ | awk '{print $2}')
    out=/Users/$USER/Desktop

    adb shell am dumpheap $PID $HPROF
    adb pull $HPROF $out
}
```

To use it from command line, connect android with usb and run:

```bash
heap_dump my.app.package.name
```

Heapdump is saved under `/Users/$USER/Desktop`